# How to transform a Primal to a Dual involving a combination of decision variables in some constraints?

Tags: linear-programming, mathematical-modeling, integer-programming

I have an Primal Integer Linear Program where in some constraints there is a combination of two 0-1 decision variables say $A[u,x]$ and $B[u,v,x,y]$ (the indices here are not necessaray to be the same) in the form of "if then constraint" that handles some special cases of my problem. One constraint looks like this:
$$
for (u,v) \in A:
for (x,y) \in E : A[u,x] + A[v,y] <=B[u,v,x,y]+1 .(I)
$$

I would like to construct the Dual ILP and being not expert in Linear Programming I am wondering if in the Dual I have to take care of the meaning of constraint and keep the same behaviour as in the Primal? In other words, do I have to come up with a constraint doing the same job in the Dual as in the Primal?

Grateful to any suggestions and clarifications.

Comment: The dual of a MIP is a difficult concept. The usual notion of duality only applies to LPs.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen there is a method to apply in iorder to transform the Primal to a Dual. My question is does this transformation affects the meaning of the constraints involving the combination of decision variables or not ? Yet, from your answer if I am not wrong, you mean that primal ILPs does not have dual ILPs ?

Comment: Standard duality does not apply to MIP models.